# algorithm to sort co-ordinates by distance from a given point

Tags: algorithm, sorting, coordinates, spatial

I understand that this is a common problem but I couldnt find an algorithm for sorting in optimal time. I just need a name for some algorithms used to solve such problem. Many of the searches resulted in SQL queries but Im looking for an algorithm that would take a list of co-ordinates in 2D space and a point in the same space, the output would be a sorted list where the co-ordinates are sorted based on the distance from the give point ( or something similar ).

Comment: Calculate all the distances to the target point, sort these distances (using [whatever algorithm you want](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)) - what's the problem?

Comment: I want to know if there is a better algorithm that can produce the result with better time complexity.

Comment: The best time complexity that you can achieve is `O(n log n)` for a worst case scenario, since no known sorting algorithm seems to have perfected it, till now.

Comment: @HarshGupta O(n log n) has actually been **proven** as a lower bound for comparison-based sorting.

Comment: @maver1k You'll probably need to benchmark a few options - there is no algorithm that outperforms all the others in all scenario's. However, I suspect this is part of some larger problem you're trying to solve more efficiently, where you should actually be entirely rethinking your approach, not trying to improve some parts of your current approach, or you're trying to improve on something before you know it's too slow.

Comment: Hmm, the question is based on one of the interview questions online. Calculating the distance with each co-orninate and doing a sort would work. But I was more curious if there is any standard way to attack problems involving co-ordinates? Other than the generic sorting algorithms.

Comment: `O(n)` if you have a pre-processed distance matrix

Comment: This might be a bit picky, but what exactly is the interview question? It is not stated in the initial question, instead an explanation is given that using a sorting algorithm would yield the desired result.

Comment: The only "trick" is that you can optimize the distance calculation. That is, distance is `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`. But if you're just interested in which distance is larger, you don't have to do the square root operation. Because if `sqrt(a) > sqrt(b)` then `a > b`.